# SWreveal remove and add back button in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BWGl.png)I tried like this:

```
 SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
        if ( revealViewController )
        {
            [self.sidebarButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
            [self.sidebarButton setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
            [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
        }
```

Thank you..!

Comment: Please can someone help me i want to remove Swreveal where menu working and i want add back defoult button after push view controller then back button

Comment: describe proper question bro

Comment: i dont want swreveal (already enble the view controller) i just wants remove it and back button wants. how to do this please

Comment: i added image not open menu its will go on popview controller now getting

Comment: I don't understand the question, are you presenting a new view controller, if so, how ? What exactly do you want to do with the left navigation item and under which conditions ?

Comment: You can elaborate more your question in order to help you?